# How to make a top down 2D ball rolling

Tags: libgdx, rotation, box2d

I am developing a top down game similar to 8 pool billard with libgdx and box2d. How do i make a 2d ball texture look like its rolling when force is applied like this:

[image]

So it feels actually 3d ?

For example if this is our ball texture:

[image]

Comment: Presumably you'd scroll the texture in the direction opposite the direction the ball is rolling? What have you tried so far, and how have the results turned out?

Comment: I couldnt try anything since i have no idea where to start :/ as a cs student so far i develeoped only very simple 2d platform games :(

Comment: @lastpeony4 - When you developed 2D platform games, you had some objects that were animated? If yes, can't you use the same method to animate your pool balls? The solution is to basically UV-scroll your ball texture, like DMGregory hinted about.

Comment: good question. i like to know about it that how games like miniclips pool do that. its a 2d physics but balls look they move in 3d. i think thats a 3d object there as make a spritesheet for ball rolling is not efficient.

Comment: I guess there are few solutions for this.first one is scroll the texture,second is sprite sheet and 3rd is using actual 3d model.still looking for some code examples though